# Yosemite corestorage volumes not created in order

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, partitioning

I need to create multiple partitions in a Yosemite(10.10.5) CoreStorage Volume in a MacBook Pro Retina mid 2014.

MACOS (Yosemire)

DEVELOPER to symlink var/local and other(s)

WINDOWS  (Windows OS)

LINUX (LINUX) *PS: it seems that linux will not load CoreStorage volumes.

HOME to make the default path of my user folder and all applications

The main idea is to make a structure that will be easy to reinstall OS X when/ if needed and then just need to create symlinks to the folders in the other partitions.
Any advice will be appreciated.

I am aware that some applications will need/like to be in the boot drive application folder, is there any way to walk around this issue ?

So I issue these commands by its order:

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1

diskutil cs deleteVolume Logical_Volume_UUID

diskutil cs createVolume BFD915CA-2745-49AF-8FA9-8FA8C7FDF97F jhfs+ MACOS 35g

diskutil cs createVolume BFD915CA-2745-49AF-8FA9-8FA8C7FDF97F jhfs+ DEVELOPER 20g

diskutil cs createVolume BFD915CA-2745-49AF-8FA9-8FA8C7FDF97F jhfs+ WINDOWS 20g

diskutil cs createVolume BFD915CA-2745-49AF-8FA9-8FA8C7FDF97F jhfs+ LINUX 20g

diskutil cs createVolume BFD915CA-2745-49AF-8FA9-8FA8C7FDF97F jhfs+ HOME 400g

Volumes are not listed in diskutil cs lis by the same order I create them.
In Disk Utility we also get different order.
I also tried to create the volumes in the opposite order but it also does not respect the order.

Now I have Yosemite in MACOS Logical Volume.

The faster solution should be rename the Logical Volumes  and resize them.

What commands should I use to resize LVs ?

Why does disk labels disk1, disk2…. don´t come in the same order as LVs were created ?

The Volumes order in Disk Utility is:

DEVELOPER

LINUX

WINDOWS

MACOS

HOME

Why not the order used to create volumes ?

MACOS

DEVELOPER

WINDOWS

LINUX

HOME

How do I fix that ?
What command should I use to encrypt HOME ?

This is what I get in diskutil cs list

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)

|

+-- Logical Volume Group BFD915CA-2745-49AF-8FA9-8FA8C7FDF97F

=========================================================

Name:         Macintosh HD

Status:       Online

Size:         499418034176 B (499.4 GB)

Free Space:   4065718272 B (4.1 GB)

|
+-< Physical Volume B5FF539C-AAFE-49D0-8F7B-78582E258A9F

|   ----------------------------------------------------

|   Index:    0

|   Disk:     disk0s2

|   Status:   Online

|   Size:     499418034176 B (499.4 GB)

|
+-> Logical Volume Family 2E18D1FC-018D-4462-B5E0-F167E2B52097

|   ----------------------------------------------------------

|   Encryption Status:       Unlocked

|   Encryption Type:         None

|   Conversion Status:       NoConversion

|   Conversion Direction:    -none-

|   Has Encrypted Extents:   No

|   Fully Secure:            No

|   Passphrase Required:     No

|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume 221937DA-D86B-4EBE-841A-E99004B573C4

|       ---------------------------------------------------

|       Disk:                  disk4

|       Status:                Online

|       Size (Total):          19999997952 B (20.0 GB)

|       Conversion Progress:   -none-

|       Revertible:            No

|       LV Name:               DEVELOPER

|       Volume Name:           DEVELOPER

|       Content Hint:          Apple_HFS

|
+-> Logical Volume Family 6AD727A4-1D7B-4BE5-BB4F-389A9475D52D

|   ----------------------------------------------------------

|   Encryption Status:       Unlocked

|   Encryption Type:         None

|   Conversion Status:       NoConversion

|   Conversion Direction:    -none-

|   Has Encrypted Extents:   No

|   Fully Secure:            No

|   Passphrase Required:     No

|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume DB7657A6-77F3-4821-8828-68ABB5E910F0

|       ---------------------------------------------------

|       Disk:                  disk2

|       Status:                Online

|       Size (Total):          19999997952 B (20.0 GB)

|       Conversion Progress:   -none-

|       Revertible:            No

|       LV Name:               LINUX

|       Volume Name:           LINUX

|       Content Hint:          Apple_HFS

|

+-> Logical Volume Family 3AD2E188-14A2-4ECD-8627-0115CA758437

|   ----------------------------------------------------------

|   Encryption Status:       Unlocked

|   Encryption Type:         None

|   Conversion Status:       NoConversion

|   Conversion Direction:    -none-

|   Has Encrypted Extents:   No

|   Fully Secure:            No

|   Passphrase Required:     No

|   |

|   +-> Logical Volume C9F4DDEC-D489-44E5-8BE4-D1847ABDAF38

|       ---------------------------------------------------

|       Disk:                  disk1

|       Status:                Online

|       Size (Total):          19999997952 B (20.0 GB)

|       Conversion Progress:   -none-

|       Revertible:            No

|       LV Name:               WINDOWS

|       Volume Name:           WINDOWS

|       Content Hint:          Apple_HFS

|

+-> Logical Volume Family 671345B8-E0E8-4CD2-994A-3D9E7DE292F1

|   ----------------------------------------------------------

|   Encryption Status:       Unlocked

|   Encryption Type:         None

|   Conversion Status:       NoConversion

|   Conversion Direction:    -none-

|   Has Encrypted Extents:   No

|   Fully Secure:            No

|   Passphrase Required:     No

|   |

|   +-> Logical Volume 10A7B3FF-E15A-4CC2-B703-BBBB98A83236

|       ---------------------------------------------------

|       Disk:                  disk3

|       Status:                Online

|       Size (Total):          34999996416 B (35.0 GB)

|       Conversion Progress:   -none-

|       Revertible:            No

|       LV Name:               MAC OS X

|       Volume Name:           MAC OS X

|       Content Hint:          Apple_HFS

|

+-> Logical Volume Family 1517DD24-A8AC-464D-ADB9-A0F20BAF1C53

    ----------------------------------------------------------

    Encryption Status:       Unlocked

    Encryption Type:         None

    Conversion Status:       NoConversion

    Conversion Direction:    -none-

    Has Encrypted Extents:   No

    Fully Secure:            No

    Passphrase Required:     No

    |

    +-> Logical Volume D37731A9-95D0-430D-A0AA-EF97E9E3FD35

        ---------------------------------------------------

        Disk:                  disk5

        Status:                Online

        Size (Total):          400000000000 B (400.0 GB)

        Conversion Progress:   -none-

        Revertible:            No

        LV Name:               HOME

        Volume Name:           HOME

        Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

This is diskutil list output:

```
/dev/disk0

  #:  TYPE NAME                    SIZE              IDENTIFIER

  0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0

  1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1

  2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         499.4 GB   disk0s2

  3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

  /dev/disk1

  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

  0:                  Apple_HFS WINDOWS                *20.0 GB    disk1

                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             C9F4DDEC-D489-44E5-8BE4-D1847ABDAF38
                             Unencrypted
  /dev/disk2

  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

  0:                  Apple_HFS LINUX                  *20.0 GB    disk2

                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             DB7657A6-77F3-4821-8828-68ABB5E910F0
                             Unencrypted
  /dev/disk3

  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

  0:                  Apple_HFS MAC OS X               *35.0 GB    disk3

                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             10A7B3FF-E15A-4CC2-B703-BBBB98A83236
                             Unencrypted
  /dev/disk4

  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

  0:                  Apple_HFS DEVELOPER              *20.0 GB    disk4

                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             221937DA-D86B-4EBE-841A-E99004B573C4
                             Unencrypted
  /dev/disk5

  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER

  0:                  Apple_HFS HOME                   *400.0 GB   disk5

                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             D37731A9-95D0-430D-A0AA-EF97E9E3FD35
                             Unencrypted
```

Comment: Please help I am stuck here, I can´t restore my Macbook without fixing this.

Answer (score -1):

In my option, what you are attempting to do is insanely stupid.

You do **NOT** need to create multiple partitions in a Yosemite(10.10.5) CoreStorage Volume in a MacBook Pro Retina mid 2014.

If you need to encrypt your OS X partition, then you need core storage for this partition.

Windows and Linux partitions should not be created via core storage. If encryption is needed, then you should use whatever method offered by each of these operating systems.